# add class not working with html5 video player using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I have a simple video block, on video ended I am displaying certain gif,

Problem:

Now when a user pauses the video the gif also shows up, meaning When the video has ended the gifs shows up now when I play again the video and pause the video the gifs show again

To do

I want when a user pauses the video the gif should not display, meaning the gif should show up only on video ended

Here is my solution

HTML

```
<div canplay id="video-block">
    <div id="video-container">
        <video id="videoplayer" playsinline muted autoplay>
            <source src="videos/good_job.mp4"></source>
        </video>
        <div id="interactive-layers">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="pause-play-button">
        <img id="play" src="images/play.png">
        <img id="pause" src="images/pause.png">
    </div>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#videoplayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", onVideoEnded);
});


function showGif(gifname) {
        $("#gif-data").remove();
        var gif = $("<div id='gif-data'><audio class='audio' id='gifaudio'  autoplay src='" + gifs[gifname].audio + "'></audio><img class='gif' id='animatedgif' src='" + gifs[gifname].gif + "?rand=" + Math.random() + "'></div>")
        $("#interactive-layers").append(gif);
}


function onVideoEnded(e) {

        showGif("ed22");

}


$("#pause-play-button").on("click", function () {
        clearTheTimeout();
        if ($("#video-block video")[0].paused == true) {
                $("#gif-data").addClass("hidegif");
                $("#video-block video")[0].play();
                $("#pause").css("display", 'block');
                $("#play").css("display", "none");
        } else {
                $("#video-block video")[0].pause();
                $("#audioplayer")[0].pause();
                $("#gif-data").removeClass("hidegif");
                $("#pause").css("display", 'none');
                $("#play").css("display", "block");
        }
});
```

CSS

```
.hidegif{
    display: none;
}
```

Unfortunately, still, my giffs shows up when I click pause video button,

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan hi, so you mean instead of ended I should use pause event? but I want to show only on ended,here is my live demo https://meed.audiencevideo.com/

Comment: Ah, sorry I thought you wanted it the other way around

Comment: Ok, so what do I need to do to solve my problem?

Comment: We can't really help without seeing a working example (your link doesn't really make the problem clear at all). The `ended` event should work fine.

Comment: if you check the link when u pause a video and wait for 4seks the gif will show up, but I want to show up only when The video is ended after 4 seks

Comment: When the video is ended the gifs shows up now when I play again the video and pause the video the gifs shows again

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem happens because element 'gif-data' created dynamically. Try to find an element inside the parent static element.

```
    $('#video-block').find("#gif-data").addClass("hidegif");
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a few months old post but in my experience `addEventListener` not works all the time with Jquery but the `.on` event works. so when you are listening the ended event, do it with `.on` and write the showGif function inside it.